Fundamental and derived physical quantities
I read that fundamental physical quantities are independent of each other but, if we write length = velocity x time, then length depends on the time interval so how come it is independent?

A base unit of measurement, or fundamental unit, is adopted for a base quantity within a conventionally chosen subset of physical quantities, such as the SI base units: meter, kilogram, second, ampere, kelvin, mole, and candela. These quantities are independent; no quantity in the subset can be expressed in terms of the others.
For example, mass is an independent fundamental quantity. While the equation $F = ma$ ($\text{force} = \text{mass} \times \text{acceleration}$) implies mass interacting with acceleration, it does not imply dependency of mass, a fundamental quantity, on acceleration, a derived quantity, just an application example.
A good way to help you see this is the unit vectors $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$ in Cartesian coordinates, which independently define directions in three-dimensional space. Similarly, fundamental units define independent dimensions in physical measurements.
Using these fundamental quantities, one can define derived quantities such as velocity ($\text{velocity} = \text{length}/\text{time}$) and acceleration ($\text{acceleration} = \text{velocity}/\text{time}$).
